# iOS 8 Interactive notifications not showing buttons by default

Tags: ios, notifications

I'm working with the new interactive notifications in iOS 8; it fails to get the action buttons `(in "banner mode")` to show up by default. As it is now I have to slide down on top of the notification to see them.

Is this the default behavior, or is my code rotten?

For the images below I am using `XCode 6.1.1 + iOS 8.1 (Simulator)`

**What I get:**

[image: What I get]

**What I want:**

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behaviour and no problem with your code.

For more details refer to the below tutorial, result is same as yours.
http://www.thinkandbuild.it/interactive-notifications-with-notification-actions/

Answer (score 0):

Its a default behaviour. Don't worry about this. [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIUserNotificationAction_class/index.html):

> When a notification is delivered, the system displays a button for each custom action associated with the notification. Tapping a button launches your app (either in the foreground or background) and gives you a chance to perform the indicated action. You use this class to specify the text that is displayed in the button and the information your app needs to perform the corresponding action.

Answer (score 0):

The options are not default behaviour. That can be done via - [UIUserNotificationCategory](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIUserNotificationCategory_class/index.html)

Refer this WWDC video - https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?include=713

It's pretty straight forward and easy to implement. Let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is behaving normally. All that needs to be done is to drag down the bottom horizontal bar in the banner and the action buttons would be visible in the banner.

PS - As of iOS8. Once iOS9 comes in in a few more days, no guarantees if this is how it will still be.